# Views data relationships?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to figure out how add a relationship in a view_data...

I have a hook_views_data which sets up the base table and a group called List. It has two tables

1. Main List
2. List Contents

And they are related via a list_id. I have a table -> join to join the table with the list contents and all that fun stuff and that all seems to be working. But when I add a relationship for List Contents it won't show any List Contents fields.

So I can get List Name and List ID no problem, I add a relationship to List and a contextual filter for List ID but after I add a relationship I still cannot access any of the `$data['list']` array members (so product id or nid or what not).

Any idea what I am missing?

```
  $data['lists']['table']['group']  = t('Lists');

  $data['lists']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'list_id',
    'title' => t('Lists'),
    'help' => t('TODO:'),
    'entity type' => 'commerce_product',
    'access query tag' => 'commerce_product_access',
  );

  $data['lists']['table']['join'] = array(
    'commerce_List' => array(
      'left_field' => 'list_id',
      'field' => 'list_id'
    )
  );

  // Expose the List id.
  $data['lists']['list_id'] = array(
    'title' => t('List ID'),
    'help' => t("The List ID."),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
    'relationship' => array(
      'title' => t('List'),
      'help' => t("Relate this List to its contents"),
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'base' => 'commerce_List',
      'base field' => 'list_id',
      'field' => 'list_id',
      'label' => t('List contents'),
    ),
  );

  // Expose the List name.
  $data['lists']['name'] = array(
    'title' => t('List Name'),
    'help' => t('List name'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    )
  );

  // Expose the product ID.
  $data['list']['product_id'] = array(
    'title' => t('Product ID'),
    'help' => t('The unique internal identifier of the product.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'commerce_product_handler_field_product',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'relationship' => array(
      'title' => t('Product'),
      'help' => t("Relate this List to its owner's user account"),
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'base' => 'commerce_product',
      'base field' => 'product_id',
      'field' => 'product_id',
      'label' => t('List product display'),
    ),
  );

  // Expose the product type.
  $data['list']['nid'] = array(
    'title' => t('Nid'),
    'help' => t('The human-readable name of the type of the product.'),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'relationship' => array(
      'title' => t('Product display (node)'),
      'help' => t("Relate this List to its owner's user account"),
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'base' => 'node',
      'base field' => 'nid',
      'field' => 'nid',
      'label' => t('List product display'),
    ),
  );

  // Expose the creator uid.
  $data['lists']['uid'] = array(
    'title' => t('Uid'),
    'help' => t("The owner's user ID."),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_user',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_user_uid',
      'name field' => 'name', // display this field in the summary
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'title' => t('Owner'),
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_user_name',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'relationship' => array(
      'title' => t('Owner'),
      'help' => t("Relate this List to its owner's user account"),
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'base' => 'users',
      'base field' => 'uid',
      'field' => 'uid',
      'label' => t('List owner'),
    ),
  );

  // Expose links to operate on the product.
  $data['list']['delete_List'] = array(
    'field' => array(
      'title' => t('Delete'),
      'help' => t('Provide a simple link to delete the product from the List.'),
      'handler' => 'commerce_List_handler_field_product_link_delete',
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was missing some parts for my second table. Any table used in this views data hook needs to have a group. Adding

```
  $data['list']['table']['group']  = t('List');

  $data['list']['table']['join'] = array(
    'lists' => array(
      'left_field' => 'list_id',
      'field' => 'list_id'
    )
  );
```

Fixed it.